# How to edit record in a text file using java?

Tags: java, file-io, text-files

I have a text file which have records like this:

```
JOHNY 412563
SARAH 147852369
```

These records define the username and password of user account.

I wrote a simple method to edit the password of a record.

The way of editing password is sending the username you want to edit and the new password then the method should make edition of the password. But nothing happens and it copies the new data into temporary file but not back again to the main file.

Here is the method I wrote:

```
public int change_pass(String username, String password) {

 boolean checked = true;

 try {
     File f = new File("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\accounts.txt");
     File tempFile = new File("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\accounts2.txt");
     BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

     Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
     Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);

     while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
         String currentLine = sc.nextLine();
         String[] tokens = currentLine.split(" ");
         if(Objects.equals(tokens[0], username) && checked) {
             currentLine = tokens[0]+" "+password;
             checked = false;
         }
         writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    writer.close(); 
    sc.close();
    f.delete();
    boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(f);
    if(successful == true) {
       return 1;
    } catch(Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
  return 0;
}
```

This is my main program i wrote:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String newpass = null;
System.out.println("Change account password !!");
System.out.println("Validate your account please !!");
System.out.printf("Username: ");
a1.setUsername(sc.next().toUpperCase());
System.out.printf("Old Password: ");
a1.setPassword(sc.next());

Scanner y = null;
try{
    y = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\?????\\Downloads\\accounts.txt"));
    boolean checkaccount = false;
    while(y.hasNext()) {
        String a = y.next();
        String b = y.next();
        if((a == null ? a1.getUsername() == null : a.equals(a1.getUsername())) && (b == null ? a1.getPassword() == null : b.equals(a1.getPassword())))
            checkaccount = true;
    }
    if(checkaccount) {
        System.out.println("Your account has been verified successfully.");
    } else
        System.out.println("Wrong username or password ... try again.");

    System.out.printf("New Password: ");
    newpass = sc.next();
    if(newpass.length() >= 6)  {
        if(c1.change_pass(a1.getUsername(), newpass) == 1)
            System.out.println("Password has been changed successfully.");
        else
            System.out.println("Error occurred during changing password, try again.");
    } else
        System.out.println("Short password: password must be at least 6 characters.");
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Post edited, see format now.

Comment: the question is when i call this method in main program and passing username and password to it. it doesn't work and no edition happened

Comment: f.delete() returns boolean - check it's value. it can not remove most likely and later can not rename.

Comment: run through your program with a debugger, its exactly what they are made for

Comment: so you are saying that the tempFile actually gets written correctly? so it's a problem with the delete and the rename?

Comment: So are any exceptions being thrown?  Is the rename call happening?  What value is `successful` being set to?

Comment: Does your application have permission to delete the original file?

Comment: @SlipperySeal yes that's right, the temp file get written correctly but it should back the new data to the main file and override it.

Comment: post edited, add main program code that calls the method.

Comment: ahem...... formatting. I did it for you this time. Please learn Java formatting rules and try to follow them. Seriously.

Comment: you forget my question and just asked me for formatiing

Comment: Others are working on your question -- I'm just trying to help you make it readable. If you post poorly formatted code no one will read it, and many will down-vote it.

Answer (score 1):

After a long time i finally found the solution of my question:

It's very simple: just add this line:

```
y.close();
```

before the line:

```
if(checkaccount)
```

Explanation: file is still open while you are attempt to edit it. 
So it gives error and cannot be edited until you close it.

So you must close file before editing.

Comment: I wonder how couldn't anyone solve this simple problem. anyway thanks to all of you

Comment: Congrats on  your solving it, and 1+ to your answer. One reason for your finding it and others not -- you're the only one with fully functioning compilable code that reproduces the problem. In the future, consider creating and posting a [mcve] that would allow us to compile/run/test/modify/correct the code.